# What should I put in ESTA if staying in the US for a few days before going on to Canada?

Tags: usa, transit, canada, international-travel, esta

I am about to apply for my US ESTA, and there is a question asking if the travel to the US is in transit for another country. I am planning to fly to New York from the UK, stay for a couple of days, and then fly on to Canada. At the other end I will get a bus from Canada to the US and then fly home from there. Do I answer yes or no to the transit question?

Comment: ‘Transit’ typically means short-term (usually max 24 hours) travel across or through the a country on the way to another country. If you’re staying for 2+ days you’re visiting, IMHO.

Comment: @Traveller yet a garden-variety C-1 US transit visa can authorize up to 29 days of presence in the US.  It's archaic, I know, but there it is.  The US really puts more emphasis on purpose than on duration.

Comment: @phoog I'd love to see the incredulous looks given to someone who applies for a transit visa saying they want to take a ship from Europe to New York, ride a bicycle (fairly quickly) across the country, and catch a freighter to Asia from the west coast.

Comment: @ZachLipton yeah, or just to walk from Abbottsford, BC to Tijuana.  I suspect that the purpose would be deemed recreational rather than transportational, and a B visa required.

Comment: @phoog Usually you go the other way.

Comment: @AzorAhai that depends on the time of year.

Comment: @phoog: That's a rather generous amount of slack, true, but what if the airline goes bust or some other catastrophe happens and you get stranded? A sensible person would apply for an extension, of course, but if everyone applied at the same time, it could get ugly.

Answer (score 25):

Answer *no.*  You should only answer *yes* if the sole purpose of your trip is transit.  In your case, the purpose of your trip is twofold: one purpose is to get to Canada, but another purpose, however secondary it may be, is to spend a few days in New York.